# Windows firefox and MAC chrome maximize command not working

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

In selenium using   `driver.manage().window().maximize();` the command I Maximize my browser its working fine for my windows chrome but when I run the test case on MAC PC chrome browser or any Mozilla browser it does not maximize my browser? Is there any solution to solve this problem?

Comment: what is the error you are getting for firefox?

Comment: it will not show any error..It's just not work

Comment: when firefox is launched using your code, is it not maximized by default?

Comment: Please Read the post carefully..Its just not maximized for Mozilla

Answer (score 1):

Try it for chrome:

```
ChromeOptions option = ChromeOptions();
option.add_argument("--start-maximized");
```

Comment: I will try this but what will be the solution for Mozilla

Comment: Let me check @zsbappa

Comment: For firefox  I don't have solution. I tried with Firefoxoptions but it didn't work. For chrome and safari it works

Comment: Thanks buddy, if i got it share it with u

Answer (score 0):

The argument "--kiosk" for ChromeOptions on MAC open a full screen driver. The maximize option on Windows OS works different as MacOS. On Windows is close to a full screen and on MacOs is like adjust to top and bottom.

```
ChromeOptions option = ChromeOptions();
option.add_argument("--kiosk");

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```